# Activating filter from JavaScript - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I just started out playing around with Angular for a project.

I'm using 'angular-google-maps' to get a Google Map on the page and on this map I have markers. I've successfully managed to catch the click events on the markers. However, when a marker is clicked, I need a filtered ul to be updated. The filter is controlled by a form.

At first I tried changing the value of the input-field in the form with JS, hoping that Angular would detect via the onchange event. It didn't. So I did some Googling and found out that I need to change the model in the scope. So I did that. `$scope.search.$ = marker.name;`

It works now, but only **after** you have first typed something into the field by hand. I need this "click marker to update filter" functionality to work directly after page load. Upon trying to change `$scope.search.$ = marker.name;` before the field has been typed into, I get this error from the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined`
Does anyone have a clue how I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Solved it by putting

```
$scope.search = {
    $: null
};
```

inside my controller. Seems like the model is not put in the scope by Angular until the form is edited when the model is only defined there using `<input ng-model="search.$" id="search-field" type="text" name="search-filter" placeholder="Sök i fritext" autofocus>`...

Comment: Can you show us the relevant portion of your code, preferably using something like jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co?

Comment: I assume that click function has no access to $scope.search, or $scope.search is not created yet, although it seems that you use wrong assignment for model `$scope.search = marker.name`. The trailing $ has a different purpose that you think it does

Comment: I am not creating ```$scope.search``` on my own. It's generated by the ng-models on the input fields...